# Zend Framework can't find Model

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a model, `Application_Model_DbTable_Login`, located in `Application > models > DbTable > Application_Model_DbTable_Login.php`.

In my controller, `LoginController`, I am trying to instantiate the Model, but it's saying that it can't find it. Here is the exact error: Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Login' not found in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/AssetLibrary/application/controllers/LoginController.php on line 8.

I just started working with Zend Framework. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file

```
Application_Model_DbTable_Login.php to Login.php
```

and ensure the class within is defined as

```
<?php
class Model_DbTable_Login extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{}
```

Then in your controller call

```
$model = new Model_DbTable_Login();
```

Comment: Ok, I did all three steps and I am getting the same error. "Fatal error: Class 'Model_DbTable_Login' not found in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/AssetLibrary/application/controllers/LoginController.php on line 8"

Comment: humm - what do you have in your index.php and BootStrap.php? dump the details into an answer below

Comment: The previous error message was "Application_Model_DbTable_Login not found". Now, it's "Model_DbTable_Login not found", no `Application_`. So it seems now be an appnamespace issue. The default appnamespace is "Application" so, unless you have explicitly set an empty appnamespace somewhere in your bootstrap process, then you need to instantiate your model using `$model = new Application_Model_DbTable_Login()`.